# Primary phone of type Mobile doesn't show in the Primary phone profile field

Tags: profile

When you add a field of phone type Primary - Phone in a profile for a contact, if that phone type is Mobile, it does not appear in the profile field. Specifying it as Primary - Mobile will allow it to appear. However, a contact can only have one primary phone number.

Contact details:

[image]

Profile field detail:

[image]

Profile view detail:
[image]

It seems that you can't display the primary phone number whatever type it is; you have to specify that it is a Phone or a Mobile, for example. I should have thought that it should be possible to specify that the Primary phone number of whatever type should be displayed in the profile.

Any suggestions?